# Register user to repository Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, spring-security

I have a runtime repository of accounts (I am not using database), and I want to be able to register new accounts during runtime. I have a controller specialized just for that.

Other than that, I have a controller that requires authentication. Please note I don't have any graphical form, just the API, so the authentication must come from the HTTP request.

**RegisterAccountController.java**: saves to repository and returns a JSON password

```
@Autowired
private AccountService service;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/account", produces = "application/json")
public String create(@RequestBody String accountId) {
        String password = service.generatePassword();
        service.save(accountId, password);

        return password;
    }
}
```

**AccountService.java**: saves the user to local runtime repository

```
@Autowired
private AccountRepository repository;

@Autowired
private PasswordGenerator pwGenerator;

public void save(String accountId, String password) {
    repository.save(new Account(accountId, password));
}

public String generatePassword() {
    // random password is returned
    return pwGenerator.generate();
}
```

**AccountRepository.java**

```
// accountId --> account
private Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();


public Account findById(String accountId) {
    return accounts.get(accountId);
}


public void save(Account account) {     
    accounts.put(account.getAccountId(), account);
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired  
    private AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(accountDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // permit public POST to '/account' endpoint
        http.authorizeRequests()
                            .antMatchers("/account").permitAll() // allow everyone to open account
                            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated() // all other endpoints authenticated
                            .and().httpBasic();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

**AccountDetailsService.java**

```
@Service
public class AccountDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private final AccountRepository repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String accountId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = repository.findById(accountId);
        return new User(account.getId(), account.getPassword(), Collections.emptySet()); // no granted authorities
    }
}
```

**AuthorizedController.java**: only authorized account can access it

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/hello", produces = "application/json")
public String hello() {
    return "Hello, authenticated!";
}
```

Now the problem is that whenever I register a new user in my **RegisterAccountController**, and try to hit the **AuthorizedController** afterwards, I can't login with the credentials for the registered user.

For example, a user "Joe" was registered, and was given a random password "12345678". Now, I hit the "/hello" endpoint with credentials "Joe", "12345678" and I am getting **Unauthorized exception**, as if the authentication part of the app is not picking up information from the accounts repository.

Please try to help with some advice.

Comment: In you HttpSecurity put this config `http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/account/**").permitAll().and().httpBasic();` and let me know the status

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Now the "/hello" controller doesn't ask for authentication (because there is no anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()). And if I leave that part as it was, then it again asks for the authentication but user credentials still won't work.

Comment: Well i missed one thing, update it with `http.csrf().disable().anonymous().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/account/**").permitAll().and().httpBasic();`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Do you want me to leave the "anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()" part or not?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Now even the "/account" endpoint throws "Unauthorized: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"

Comment: Then remove `**` after `account/` `antMatchers("/ac‌​count")`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Exactly the same result... well in Postman, but from Chrome Restlet Client the /account/ works. And when trying "/hello" then it doesn't ask for auth

Comment: Listen, to identify your problem, need to look resource server configuration also. As it works together.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Where can i find that configuration?

Comment: You can search a tutorial for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you keep getting **Unauthorized exception** is that in your **AccountDetailsService.java** you didn't specify it's permission.
Your code must be something like

```
@Service
public class AccountDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private final AccountRepository repository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String accountId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Account account = repository.findById(accountId);
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    return new User(account.getId(), account.getPassword(), 
   authorities);
}
}
```